# Manual GL_REPEAT in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

Currently I have a texture atlas that is 2048 x 2048 pixels set up with three 512 x 512 textures stored, and I am only applying one texture to the object. So I used the following code to position the texture coordinates (from zero to 1) to the correct position on the texture atlas for that texture:

```
color = texture2D(tex_0, vec2(0.0, 1024.0/2048.0) + mod(texture_coordinate*vec2(40.0), vec2(1.0))*vec2(512.0/2048.0));
```

The problem is that when I apply this, there is a black border around the texture. I presume that this is because OpenGL can't blend the two pixels at the place of that border.

So how do I get rid of the border?

Edit*
I have already tried to move the starting and ending boundaries in toward the center of the texture and that didn't work.

Edit*
I found the source of the problem, the automatic mipmap generation is blending the textures in the texture atlas together. This means I have to write my own mipmapping function. (As far as I can tell)

If anyone has any better ideas, please do post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a normal 2D texture as the texture atlas with a grid of textures, I used the `GL_2D_TEXTURE_ARRAY` functionality to create a 3D texture that mipmapped correctly and repeated correctly. That way the textures did not blend together at higher mipmap levels.

Comment: Hmm... A nice and elegant solution. Does that mean that texture atlases are obsolete with modern GL?

Comment: Well... Im not actually sure how the performance of the two methods compare, which means that the normal texture atlas method may be faster even though the texture array method is more elegant. That would be something worth looking into.